# Call to a member function getAccountNo() on null Magento 2

Tags: checkout, shipping, javascript, jquery, magento-2.0.2

I'm extending `shipping method` section in `checkout` page, and it's showing well.

But it's throwing error while clicking next button after filling `shipping address` and `shipping method` information in `checkout` page.

> Error: Fatal Error: 'Call to a member function getCommentCode() on
>   null'

for this I have written below code:

**Learning/ABlock/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="save-in-quote" type="Learning\ABlock\Model\Checkout\ShippingInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Learning/ABlock/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="Learning_ABlock" instance="Learning\ABlock\Model\Observer\SaveAccountNoObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Learning/ABlock/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="account_no" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**Learning/ABlock/Model/Checkout/ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\ABlock\Model\Checkout;

class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{

    protected $quoteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        $AccountNo = $extAttributes->getAccountNo();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quote->setAccountNo($AccountNo);
    }
}
```

**Learning/ABlock/Model/Observer/SaveAccountNoObserver.php**

```
<?php

namespace VLCSolutions\ABlock\Model\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveAccountNoObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager)
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quoteRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository');
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
        $order->setAccountNo( $quote->getAccountNo() );

        return $this;
    }

}
```

**Learning/ABlock/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="additional_block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Learning_ABlock/js/view/checkout/shipping/additional-block</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**Learning/ABlock/view/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/additional-block.js**

```
define([
    'uiComponent'

], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Learning_ABlock/checkout/shipping/additional-block'
        }    
    });
});
```

**Learning/ABlock/view/web/template/checkout/shipping/additional-block.html**

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="account_no">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Enter Account Number'"></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input-text" id="account_no" name="account-no" type="text" ></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

see below image showing my custom field

[image]

when I debugging `$addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();` is returning null.

Could you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Comment: Does your observer event trigger or not?

Comment: @PrashantValanda, Yes it's came to my `ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php` file but `$addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();` returning null.

Comment: @SohelRana, any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to pass value through js, in this case you need to overwrite following js **Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js**

So you go with following way:

Create **Learning/ABlock/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'Learning_ABlock/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'
        }
    }
};
```

Create **Learning/ABlock/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js**

```
/*global define,alert*/
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address'
    ],
    function (
        $,
        ko,
        quote,
        resourceUrlManager,
        storage,
        paymentService,
        methodConverter,
        errorProcessor,
        fullScreenLoader,
        selectBillingAddressAction
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            saveShippingInformation: function () {
                var payload;

                if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
                    selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
                }

                payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                        billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
                        shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes:{
                            account_no: $('[name="account_no"]').val()
                        }
                    }
                };

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

                return storage.post(
                    resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
                    JSON.stringify(payload)
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                        paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        errorProcessor.process(response);
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Actually you need to pass input value by **extension_attributes**

```
extension_attributes:{
                            account_no: $('[name="account_no"]').val()
                        }
```

One more things, modify your **Learning/ABlock/view/web/template/checkout/shipping/additional-block.html**

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="account_no">
            </span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input-text" id="account_no" name="account_no" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see [here](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date) as an example.

Comment: Thank You for posting answer, and it's working perfect. Could you please tell me how can I validate, let's say If I select custom shipping method it will visible otherwise hide it.

Comment: in this case check -> Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js , selectShippingMethod

Comment: K I will back after I observing the functionality.

Comment: It's very hard to understand, If it possible give a simple example of code?

Comment: inside selectShippingMethod, using 'shippingMethod.carrier_code' , you can get your method code. If your method is selected then show your field by jquery.

Comment: Yes I have done above functionality like **show/hide** `textbox` thanks for your valuable suggestion. I have one more doubt here. When user select **custom shipping** method `textbox` value mandatory otherwise not require. I have tried but it's not working. Could you please suggest me on this?

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to set `textbox` as mandatory field?

Comment: How can i do same with one step checkout? if possible can you please help me?