# Make delivery date on checkout required

Tags: magento2, checkout, delivery-date

I already success adding an input for `delivery date` in checkout page based on this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110906/call-to-a-member-function-getaccountno-on-null-magento-2). But, the problem is, customer **still can skip the input**, and click next to finish the order. How can i made it `required` and **customer should fill it before click next**? I already tried to add `required` in the input but it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below code inside your input tag:

```
data-validate="{required:true}"
```

like

```
<input type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" class="background-none"  value="" name="registrant[0][firstname]" title="<?php echo __("First Name")  ?>" id="firstName" class="input-text required-entry">
```

Hope it help you!

Comment: No it's not work, though it's not that simple to only adding `data-validate="{required:true}"`

Comment: How do you insert you template? Use reference in XML file (Layout) or just insert your templte? Maybe your input is not inside the <form> tag so it doesn't take required. Please post what layout you reference and the .phtml file you added.

Comment: You could check the link that i add in my question, it's all the same with my case.

Comment: Try add <div class="field required"> outside the input. If It doesn't work, maybe you have to add custom js code to handle when click to Next button. I'm not sure.

Comment: Found it, in `\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html`, there's `novalidate="novalidate"` in the form that made the required not work. Thank you for helping to find the answer.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can set attribute value with "readonly" and set custom validation using jQuery to not proceed if not selected date value