# Checkout data save action

Tags: magento2, php, onepage-checkout

I want to add some sql before the customer checkout like in the picture below.
What is the file that handle the checkout? Is it `SaveOrder.php`at `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage`? because I have tried to do some sql there, but nothing happen after checkout.

[image: checkout]

Answer (score 1):

The checkout is done with various requests to the REST API. The POST-requests to `/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/payment-information` and `/V1/carts/mine/payment-information` are used in particular. You have:

- `savePaymentInforamtion()` that just saves the payment information
- `savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder()` that creates the actual order

Both these methods are public methods of the `Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface` service contract, so my best guess is you write a plugin/interceptor that catches any of those 2 public methods and it should work just fine.

Comment: But can i edit the checkout controller or block which saving the order? Because i tried to add "shipping date" at the checkout, so i need to save it to my own table before the magento save the order.

Comment: shipping date is a datepicker anyway

Comment: You can add a datepicker to the checkout page using UI Components and inject them into the checkout, there are some of articles on SE that tackle this (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94239/calendar-control-in-checkout-page-in-magento-2/94266 for example). To handle the saving of the date, you might want to look at extension attributes and use the `before`-type-of-method when writing your plugin.

Comment: How could i get the date from plugin? Because i want to save the data item on quote (product id, sku, etc) and the date to my custom table. Sorry for asking too much, im still new with magento.