# How to add datepicker field in Checkout?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.6, checkout-page, custom-field, datepicker

I want to add a **date picker** field into the checkout page but I have no idea where to start.

I have tried this [Add date picker in checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197513/add-date-picker-in-checkout-page#197518) but it's not working for me.

We are having the below folder structure:

```
app\code\siva\mymodule\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html
```

In shipping.html, we have the form which needs to be shown on the frontend.

Now, can I add both the HTML input field and JS in the same file, shipping.html?

If anyone got the delivery date field works in Checkout, please help me with this.

**Updated Code in shipping-mixin.js:**

```
   define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-billing-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'mage/translate'
], function(
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    customer,
    addressList,
    addressConverter,
    quote,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    createBillingAddress,
    selectBillingAddress,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    checkoutData,
    $t
) {
    'use strict';
    $('#conform-account-scola-btn').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#onepage-guest-register-button').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#loa').hide(); 
    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'DCKAP_School/shipping'
            },
            setShippingInformation: function () {
                var flag=false;
                var count = 0;
                var scrollTo = '';
                if($('input[name=school-or-private-person]').val() == 'school'){

                    $(".school-required-entry").each(function() {
                        if (this.value == 0 || this.value == '') {
                            count++;
                            //$(this).next('.school_err').html("This is a required field.");
                $(this).next('.school_err').html("Vänligen fyll i detta obligatoriska fält.");
                            $(this)[0].style.borderColor = "#ed8380";
                            $(this).next('.school_err').css("display", "block");
                            if(count==1){
                                scrollTo = "#"+$(this).attr('id');
                            }
                            flag=true;
                        }else{
                            $(this).next('.school_err').html('');
                $(this)[0].style.borderColor = "";
                            if(this.value != '')
                            {
                              if($("#school-display").css('display') == 'block' ){
                               $("#schoolsearch").next('.school_err').html("Vänligen klicka på din skola från listan nedan");
                               $("#schoolsearch").next('.school_err').css("display","block");
                               $("#schoolsearch").css("borderColor", "#ed8380");
                   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 180 }, "slow");
                              }
                            } 
                        }
                    });

                    if (flag) {
                        if($("#school-display").css('display') == 'block' ){
                          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 180 }, "slow");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $(scrollTo).offset().top
                          });  
                        }                        
                        return false;
                    }
                var firstname = $('#dc_shipping_firstname').val();
                var lastname = $('#dc_shipping_lastname').val();
                $('#shipping-new-address-form [name="firstname"]').val(firstname).keyup();
                $('#shipping-new-address-form [name="lastname"]').val(lastname).keyup();
                $('#billing-address-form [name="firstname"]').val(firstname).keyup();
                $('#billing-address-form [name="lastname"]').val(lastname).keyup();

                }
                else if ($('input[name=school-or-private-person]').val() == 'private')
                {
                   if ($("#customer-email").val() == 0 || $("#customer-email").val() == '') {
                    $("#customer-email").css("borderColor","#ed8380");
                    $(".input-text.mage-error").next('.school_err').css("display","none");
                    $("#customer-email-error").html("Vänligen fyll i detta obligatoriska fält."); 
                   }
                } 

                if (this.validateShippingInformation() && this.validateBillingInformation()) {
                    setShippingInformationAction().done(
                        function () {
                            $("#majema-school").hide();
                            $("#place-order-trigger-wrapper").show();
                            $("#custom-info").appendTo("#co-payment-form");
                            $('#custom-shipping-method-buttons-container').hide();
                            $('#custom-subtotal').hide();
                            $('.opc-block-summary .table-totals').show();
                            stepNavigator.next();
                        }
                    );
                }
            },
            validateBillingInformation: function() {

                if($('[name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"]').is(":checked")) {
                    if (this.isFormInline) {
                        var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
                        var addressData = addressConverter.formAddressDataToQuoteAddress(
                            this.source.get('shippingAddress')
                        );
                        //Copy form data to quote shipping address object
                        for (var field in addressData) {

                            if (addressData.hasOwnProperty(field) &&
                                shippingAddress.hasOwnProperty(field) &&
                                typeof addressData[field] != 'function' &&
                                _.isEqual(shippingAddress[field], addressData[field])
                            ) {
                                shippingAddress[field] = addressData[field];
                            } else if (typeof addressData[field] != 'function' &&
                                !_.isEqual(shippingAddress[field], addressData[field])) {
                                shippingAddress = addressData;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                            shippingAddress.save_in_address_book = 1;
                        }
                        var newBillingAddress = createBillingAddress(shippingAddress);
                        selectBillingAddress(newBillingAddress);
                    } else {
                        selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                var selectedAddress = $('[name="billing_address_id"]').val();
                if(selectedAddress) {
                    var res = addressList.some(function (addressFromList) {
                        if (selectedAddress == addressFromList.customerAddressId) {
                            selectBillingAddress(addressFromList);
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    });

                    return res;
                }

                this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
                this.source.trigger('billingAddress.data.validate');

                if (this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                    return false;
                }

                var addressData = this.source.get('billingAddress'),
                    newBillingAddress;

                if ($('#billing-save-in-address-book').is(":checked")) {
                    addressData.save_in_address_book = 1;
                }

                newBillingAddress = createBillingAddress(addressData);
                selectBillingAddress(newBillingAddress);

                return true;
            }

        });


initialize: function () {
                    this._super();
                    ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
                        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                            var $el = $(element);
                            //initialize datetimepicker
                            var options = {
                                minDate: 0,
                                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                            };

                            $el.datetimepicker(options);

                            var writable = valueAccessor();
                            if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                                var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                                if (propWriters && propWriters.datetimepicker) {
                                    writable = propWriters.datetimepicker;
                                } else {
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                            writable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));
                        },
                        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                            var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                            //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                            if (widget) {
                                var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                                widget.date(date);
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    return this;
                }    
    }
});
```

**Error in the console:**

[image]

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran I have tried this extension but it's not working

Comment: @siva https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197513/add-date-picker-in-checkout-page#197518 - checkout this answer

Comment: @aravind, Thanks. Let me try and update you

Comment: @siva Ok sure..

Comment: @aravind I have tried the solution but it's not working for me

Comment: Did you try using https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date?

Comment: @SohelRana, Yes, I have tried but that was not worked. Also, now, our client requirement is to create the delivery date field without using a third party plugin. I have read there is a calendar widget by default in Magento. Can I use that on Checkout page? If yes, please tell me how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a paid extension? https://www.fmeextensions.com/custom-checkout-fields-extension-magento-2.html

Comment: @DominicXigen, we want to add the datepicker field programmatically without using any extension. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'SR_MagentoCommunity/js/mixin/shipping-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/js/mixin/shipping-mixin.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'mage/translate',
        'mage/calendar'
    ], function (
        $,
        ko,
        $t
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return function (target) {
            return target.extend({
                initialize: function () {
                    this._super();
                    ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
                        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                            var $el = $(element);
                            //initialize datetimepicker
                            var options = {
                                minDate: 0,
                                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                            };

                            $el.datetimepicker(options);

                            var writable = valueAccessor();
                            if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                                var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                                if (propWriters && propWriters.datetimepicker) {
                                    writable = propWriters.datetimepicker;
                                } else {
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                            writable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));
                        },
                        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                            var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                            //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                            if (widget) {
                                var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                                widget.date(date);
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    return this;
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Now in **shipping.html** add following code:

```
<label class="label">Delivery Date</label>
<div class="control">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datetimepicker: true"  name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/>
</div>
```

***Clear static content if your Magento mode is not developer***

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it. But in the file "shipping-mixin.js", already have some code. So now, where to add the code which you suggest in "shipping-mixin.js". I have updated the question with the code. Please help me.

Comment: no problem, just copy initialize method in your code.

Comment: I have tried that, but getting an error and the error says "Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon"

Comment: Don't know how you add, can you show error and update shipping-mixin.js

Comment: I have included the updated shipping-mixin.js and screenshot of the error. Still, I'm getting the error, Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Since you have posted your answer, I'm asking you that if you have any suggestion to make this work because I have tried as per your post but still not working. The updated code is pasted in the question. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

path:-

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping/datepicker-fields.html

```
<div class="fieldset"
         data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
        <div class="field date required">
            <label class="label" for="date">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Date'"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input-date" id="date" name="date" type="date"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

path:-

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/datepicker-fields.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent'

], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/shipping/datepicker-fields'
        }
    });
});
```

> path:-
> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="additional_block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/datepicker-fields</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```